# How to get rid of the lag/stutter while playing videos with the dGPU (Nvidia Optimus)?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, lag, hardware-acceleration, optimus

I recently got a laptop that uses Nvidia Optimus, and one of the things I have noticed is that when I set the browser (any browser: Chrome, Edge...) to be executed via dGPU (in Windows preferences), all goes perfectly fine (using Google Earth web, for example, is way better), but when a webpage contains a video it is way worse than with the iGPU.

When scrolling to videos, or watching them (a Youtube video, for example), it lags, stutters... Also, I noticed that with the browser in dGPU mode, videos are being decoded with de dGPU like it should, so I don't understand what is happening.

This is not only happening in web browser but on other applications too, like when the Spotify app displays a video.

My question: Why is this happening, and is there a way to get rid of this lag without having to disable the use of dGPU on these applications?

Thanks

Comment: Laptop:   Update BIOS, Chipset driver, then Video and do a final restart to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution. It seems that going to the flags of the browser, and choosing "D3D11on12" as ANGLE graphics backend solves the problem. Howewer, I still can't find a solution for other applications.